# format the JSON into csv

Tags: python, json, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am having the data formatted in json i need to convert it into csv

The problem is number of records in each row are not same

the sample  json is

```
{"0":{"REPORT  : yes","Tmpl : AWT-STANDARD","DRS : 2.5","DraftFore : 5.2","DraftMid : 6","DraftAft : 7"},"1":{"REPORT  : yes","Tmpl : AWT-STANDARD","DraftFore : 5.2","DraftMid : 6","DraftAft : 7"},"2":{"REPORT  : yes","Tmpl : AWT-STANDARD","DraftFore : 5.2","DraftMid : 6","DraftAft : 7"}}
```

In these the attribue :DRS" is present in the 0 the row but not present in the  1 st and 2nd row.I want to give the proper format to these json file and convert these json to csv.

the code which i tried to convert the list to json is `

```
as = df['Body'].to_json(orient='columns')     
as = as.replace("[", "{")
as = as.replace("]", "}")
```

by using these code i have converted the list to the json format

The code which i tried to convert the json to csv is

```
as.to_csv(/home/o1.csv)
```

The error i got while converting to csv is "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'"

My issue is number of attributes in each rows are not same and i need to format the json and convert it into csv

Comment: Keys in dicts *don't* have a `to_csv` method. Where are you getting that from?

Comment: so how to have the method to_csv@connectyourcharger

Comment: Do you want to convert data *from* or *to* JSON? That doesn't become clear from your post.

Comment: from json i need to convert it to csv@mkrieger1

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import the [csv package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and pass `as` to it.

Comment: Even after importing csv it gives the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv @Haroldo_OK

Comment: As @mkrieger1 pointed out, this attribute does not exist. The `csv` package has functions for creating CSV.